# # Error: VLM_0040: VHDL unit cannot be compiled as the target library name is not a legal VHDL identifier

Tags: vhdl

It seems that i have some problems with the Activ-HDL student edition. When I want to compile the following error appears:

> # Error: VLM_0040: VHDL unit cannot be compiled as the target library name is not a legal VHDL identifier.

I don't know why because yesterday I installed it and today I have this error. Can someone help me.

Comment: ... and what library are you trying to compile it into?

Comment: I am trying to use the library IEEE;

Comment: The error message suggests you're trying to compile something into that (IEEE) library. Normally that contains standard libraries, you wouldn't want to extend it. So what are you actually trying to do?  If you are adding new packages, create a new library of your own and add them to it. If you're just trying to compile an ordinary project, find the actual compile command line (it'll be in a console window or logfile), add it to the question, and analyze it against the documentation, to find out which build option went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, when you compile your sources they are added to a library that has the same name as your Active-HDL design, and, as the error message suggests, if that name doesn't fall under VHDL identifier naming conventions you get the aforementioned error.

To give your design a proper name you should follow several simple rules:

- Names (or identifiers) may consist of letters, numbers and
  underscore.
- Names must start with a letter.
- None of the VHDL keywords (i.e. signal, bus, component, wait, etc.) may be reused as a name.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the (correct) answer above: the name of the library that your sources are added to is shown in the Design Browser below "Add New Library" (see image, where the library is called "hy-phen").
This name can be changed by clicking "Add new Library". By right-clicking the new library you can set it as active. Now the source code should compile into the new library (without renaming the whole Active-HDL design).

[image: library named "hy-phen"]

After setting the new library as active, the old one (with the invalid name) can be detached from the project (by right-clicking on it).

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.2 Design libraries "For a given library logical name, the actual name of the corresponding design library in the host environment may or may not be the same. A given implementation shall provide some mechanism to associate a library logical name with a host-dependent library. Such a mechanism is not defined by the language." That mechanism appears deficient.